# Spring HTTP invoker with Service Discovery

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka, service-discovery, byte-buddy, httpinvoker

Is there any framework available to use service discovery with spring HTTP invoker over rmi. ? Like Netflix euraka server or something like that.